# I cannot get logged into a myGet npm repository (sencha/extjs-ce)

Tags: npm, myget

I'm setting up a dev VirtualBox (Ubuntu) and I can't get logged into the private myGet repository through Npm. I have error 403 Invalid Login.

I can connect to myGet site with my credentials.

FYI, I am behind a secured proxy but other command line tool (composer, node, apt, curl) are working as I have set the env information.

I also tried `sudoed`.

Update:

`npm login` (without the `--registry`...) works

```
user@user-VirtualBox:/var/www$ npm login  --registry=htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/ whoami
Username: maquejp..gmail.com
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) yoyo@gmail.com
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! Registry returned 403 for PUT on htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:yoyo..gmail.com: Invalid login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-03-25T15_08_42_242Z-debug.log
user@user-VirtualBox:/var/www$ cat /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-03-25T15_08_42_242Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'login',
1 verbose cli   '--registry=htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/',
1 verbose cli   'whoami' ]
2 info using npm@5.8.0
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose npm-session 62efce47a150f6d5
5 verbose web login before first POST
6 http request → POST htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/-/v1/login
7 http 404 ← Not Found (htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/-/v1/login)
8 verbose web login not supported, trying couch
9 verbose login before first PUT { _id: 'org.couchdb.user:yoyo..gmail.com',
9 verbose login   name: 'yoyo..gmail.com',
9 verbose login   password: 'XXXXX',
9 verbose login   type: 'user',
9 verbose login   roles: [],
9 verbose login   date: '2019-03-25T15:08:40.165Z' }
10 http request → PUT htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:yoyo..gmail.com
11 http 403 ← { "error": "Invalid login", "reason": "The specified login is not valid." } (htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:yoyo..gmail.com)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As updated by Jean-Philippe:

npm login (without the --registry...) works

Doing that works.

I had that problem on the ubuntu bash on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong url in registry:

`--registry=htps://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/`

Try:
`--registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/`

Comment: Obviously, I have removed for being authorised to post here. Thank you :)